# Serializing simple class into one line in file

Tags: python, serialization

I have a very simple Python class called Post that has just 3 String fields: author, timestamp, and content.

I want to serialize a bunch of these objects into a file so I tried Pickle but that uses 3 lines per file, and I want to just iterate through each line the file and convert 1 line to 1 Post object.

What would be a simple way to serialize these into one line each?

Comment: Can you modify the `Post` class?

Answer (score 1):

One way you could store your objects is as lines of a CSV file.  Each line of the CSV file would have three comma separated values for author, timestamp and content.  Take a look at the csv library:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer

You might end up doing something like this (untested):

```
posts = [   Your Posts array   ]

with open('posts.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['author', 'timestamp', 'content']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    for p in posts:
        writer.writerow({'author': p.author, 'timestamp': p.timestamp, 'content' : p.content})
```